# Show and hide UITableView with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, animation

I'm trying to show and hide a tableView with an animation "transition from left to right & right to left"

This what i already tired it worked but after using a random values in the CGRectMake,

Do anyone can help me to fix it please

```
    -(void)Display:(UITableView *)tableView :(UIView *)view{
         tableView.alpha=1;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35
                         animations:^{
                                 tableView.frame = CGRectMake(-209, 440, 180, 209);

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                             [tableView setHidden:YES];

                         }
         ];
    }

-(void)Hide:(UITableView *)tableView :(UIView *)view :(int )tb{
    tableView.alpha=1;
    [tableView setHidden:NO];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.45
                     animations:^{
                          tableView.frame = CGRectMake(3, 442, 180, 209);

                     }
     ];
}
```

Comment: Please, show us what you already tried.

Comment: @Dave here what i tired already

Comment: @fourthnovember you say it works in the post above. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:firstView
                    toView:secondView//table view
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    [firstView.superView addSubview:secondView];

                    [firstView.superView sendSubviewToBack:firstView];
                }];
```

Comment: mityaika07 thank you, i tried ur solution it worked but for all the view not just for my tableview with a flip not a slide transition left right, me i had tried this 2 method it work but i get lost with the CGRectMake, there is maybe a better way to set the transition from left to right using this ?  without setting in random way the CGRectMake

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your question but by "transition from left to right & right to left"
do you want something like this...?

For animating out left

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{


                         self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);

                     }
                     completion:NULL];
```

For animating out right

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{


                         self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);

                     }
                     completion:NULL];
```

For animating in

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{


                         self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);

                     }
                     completion:NULL];
```

You can put table reloads etc. in your completion blocks? and then animate the tableView back in?

Comment: can u plz explain me the first points values in the CGRectMake, they work good ur samples but i have just to set the ending point not in the end of the view in top left. to do the effect slide show and hide

Comment: Sure, so CGRectMake is ordered origin.X, origin.Y, width, height... so moving the view (in this case a tableview) to the right.. we increase the origin.x if we want to move it left, we decrease.

Answer (score 0):

If you want animation like Facebook then use :- ECSlidingViewController

http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/slide-out-navigation/

Or

If you want normal animation then set frame and reduce alpha from 1.0 to 0.0 with duration.

Comment: thank you but its not what i wanted to do im just trying to display and hide a uitableView with animation

Comment: ok, then use this may be this is useful :- Initially set the frame of tableview (0,0,0,460) then in animation part (0,0,320,460)
- (void)animateView:(UIView *)theView toPosition:(CGPoint) thePosition
{
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
 // Set the center to the final postion
 // Set the transform back to the identity, thus undoing the previous scaling effect.
        theView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
 theView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
 [UIView commitAnimations];
}